# Access VBA - Cancel form Error event?

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I've set this code for one of my field (Input mask violation):

```
Private Sub Form_Error(DataErr As Integer, Response As Integer)

Const INPUTMASK_VIOLATION = 2279
      If DataErr = INPUTMASK_VIOLATION Then
         MsgBox "You didn't fill the data correctly !", vbCritical
         Response = acDataErrContinue
      End If

End Sub
```

Now, on same form I have Undo button. When I violate Input mask and click on Undo button, this Inputmask_Violation Msgbox keeps poping up. I doesn't allow me to cancel Dirty data until I fill data in field correctly.

Any option to cancel this when I click on Undo button ?

My Undo button code:

```
If Me.Dirty Then Me.Undo
```

Comment: You can put any default value in that field after showing message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this can't be done, I've tried different variaties. Input mask violation is a run-time error, so It occurs before every VBA event.